# How to get contents of NSTextFieldCell when user Quits while editing NSTextFieldCell NOT NSTextField

Tags: text, edit, exit, nsoutlineview, nstextfieldcell

The previous version of this question was closed because the moderator did not recognize that this is a cell-based Outline not a view-based outline. The answer the moderator suggested does not work for a cell-based outline.

The question as previously asked is:

I have a cell-based NSOutlineView.  How do I get the contents of the NSTextFieldCell when the user Quits the app while editing that cell.  Currently, attributedStringValue returns the contents before editing began.

Comment: From where and/or when do you want to access the cell? Is `outlineView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:byItem:` not being called the real issue?

Comment: Willeke:  You are right.  setObjectValue... is not being called when the user quits while editing.  I attempt to get the edited value when applicationShouldTerminate is called.  Is there another place I should save an edit in progress?